# LLVM Monotonic Loop detection

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm searching for a robust way to detect Monotonic Loops using llvm c++ API (3.8+) and also detect the Start and End value of the induction variable.

I did some code but it don't work to all cases. Remember that it is to version 3.8 or greater. If you know how to do this please share with us.